# How to handle authentication popup window in UI automation using Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, popupwindow

How to handle authentication popup window in UI automation using Selenium in C#

I am authoring a UI test that navigate to a website Home page. As the website internally access another site. Selenium on Firefox displays a authentication required popup window.

How do I handle the popup window using Selenium driver to enter the username and password on the popup window?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below:-

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

Give your username in place of username, same for password and change example.com with your website

OR there is one more method but it is in java you can convert it into C# by taking it's reference.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(**username**, **password**));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I don't see .get("") method on the driver. Also I don't see the alertIsPresent() etc. Are these standard Selenium C# methods?

Comment: There must a place where you are putting your URL .. right? .. Just replace it with above URL with your credentials and website name

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in your `.config file`

add key=`URL` value="http://**username**:**password**@**pasteyoururl**"

paste this in your **c# script**

```
string `variable` = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["**URL**"];
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(**variable**);
```

Try the above mentioned code, sure it will work.

This code will only work only if you read **key** from `app.config/web.config`

Answer (score 0):

```
string siteUser = "testUser";
string sitePass = "testPass";
string siteUrl = "localhost:1980"
string format = @"https://{0}:{1}@{2}/site";
string authURI = String.Format(format, siteUser, sitePass, siteUrl);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(authURI);
```

This is what worked for us

Answer (score -1):

Pass you username and password with application url like below while navigating application url:

```
http://username:passwork@applicationURL
```

Comment: The popup window is for authentication for a different URL (that the actual application is internally calling) than the actual application URL. Here are the steps: 1. Call the actual application URL. 2. Login to the application with the Azure AD Login page. 3. After logging on the home the application tries to access another URL to display some information on the home page, which is triggering the authentication required popup.

Comment: In that case what you need to do, created a firefox profile and installed AutoAuth plugin "https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoauth/" Then all your test suite on this browser. But you need to save you password and username once in profile browser